# Maltparser error

Tags: java, nlp, tweets

I am new at Maltparser and i need to parse my sentences on russian language. I found russian trained model and tried using it in Maltparser 1.5(because this russian model works only with version 1.5). i run maltparser in terminal using:

> java -jar malt.jar -c rus-test -m parse -i tweets.tab

but i get the error:

> The learner class 'org.maltparser.ml.lib.LibLinear' cannot be
>   initialized.

what's wrong with Maltparser?

Answer (score 1):

Hi! I've got the same problem, too.

It's most likely that maltparser needs more heap size. 
try  `java -Xmx5000m`  (or more, i.e. 5000m was fine for me)

If it doesn't help try run maltparser with  `-v debug`  and see what happens (in my case I've got "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space")

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The `malt.jar` package references its dependencies in the `lib` folder of the distribution. Those include the `liblinear-1.7-with-deps.jar` file that contains the needed classes. Ensure that the `lib` folder from the `malt` distribution is located next to the `malt.jar` file when you run it.